# pass router params to component object

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, vue-loader

I have view and I want to load svg based on router params, I have installed vue-loader and it is working if I hard code it.

```html
<template>
<div>
  <suit/>
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  components:{

    suit: ()=>import('../assets/svg/'+Param+'.svg')
  }
}
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

This is what I have. Instead of `Param` I want to get `this.route.params`, but when I try this I get `undefined` which is logical because components wrapper is object. Is there a way to pass a variable here or must I redo the whole thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `this.route.params`, within a component you should be using `this.$route.params`. [Vue Router Docs](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/#javascript).